# Sharing multiple thumbnails on facebook with the sharer.php

Tags: image, facebook, share

I've been trying for tha tpast 24 hours to activate the facebook sharer to share multiple thumbs. here's my code :

---

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="ShareThis Homepage" />
<meta property="og:type" content="Sharing Widgets" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.realestatephotoexpert.com/Properties/82/centrisSmall/-1.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="New listing" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ShareThis" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    stLight.options({
            publisher:'12345',
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="st_sharethis"></span>
</body>
```

I managed to display 1 thumbnail using og:url, I dont even know why its working because it suppose to be the og:image. even with this work around, i cant figure how to share multiple thumb( once log-in to facebook, be able to use the left and right arrows to select thumnail.

thx for your help